# How to fix an exit code from if/while statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to add cleanup to some existing bash scripts, their functionality relevant to this question is that they create a log file and have multiple exit statements. What I am trying to achieve is move the log file before the script exits and then exit with the same code that the original exit was invoked with, one way of doing this I've found is with trap, I've written a simple script that catches the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() {
    exit_code=$?
    echo trapped exit, code=$exit_code
    trap 'exit 0' EXIT
}  
trap cleanup EXIT
exit 4
```

If you run the script it echoes the correct exit code and exits with it. However if instead of

```
exit 4
```

I have the call to exit in an if/while loop like:

```
if [ 5>4 ] ; then
    exit 4
fi
```

I get exit code 0.

Is there a way to achieve my goal using trap or is there an alternative?

Comment: Just a syntax error: It must be `if [ 5 -gt  4 ] ; ...`

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Trying to make a stupid test case I actually wrote a very stupid test case as I am still new to bash scripting. It works like a charm now. Thank you for the helpful referrence too!

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a synonym for `test`, so `[ 5>4 ]` is equal to `test 5>4`. Bash reads this command as *run `test` and redirect file descriptor `5` to a file named `4`*, and without arguments `test` exits with `0`. See [bash manual#Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for further information.

You should have noticed that a file named `4` is created in your working directory btw.

Comment: I completely forgot about redirection, thank you for pointing that out!